# Immediate Window double/decimal addition oddity? Or behavior of the type?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

So in most calculations, I get what I expect:

```
6.23 + 5.73 = 11.96
6.5 + 52.5 = 59.0
```

However, I ran into an odd case:

```
6.41 + 52.47 = 58.879999999999995 // expected 58.88
```

Is this some odd configuration in my IDE? Or is this expected behavior of those two?

Comment: I agree Raymond, sorry, didn't see it (but didn't know to search it w/ floating point).

Answer (score 0):

That is how precision works out in many programming languages.  Get too specific with decimal values and the result doesn't turn out exactly how you want.  I believe it is a compiler issue when it converts the values to fixed binary representations, that result in those slight distortions in value.  Just avoid trying to do exact comparisons with doubles/decimals because you may be surprised.

You can do greater/less than but avoid saying something exactly equals 18.755, etc.